# Creating a RadioButton template from the Button standard template

Tags: wpf, templates

I am developing a WPF application at my company.
I want to create a RadioButton template.
I want templated RadioButtons to look like standard Buttons.
I want a checked templated RadioButton to look like a pressed standard Button.

The following screenshot part shows a line of 3 RadioButtons and the line below contains 3 Buttons.
I want my template to make the 3 RadioButtons look like the 3 Buttons.

[image]

I have read some information about template creation but I do not know how to reference parts of the Button standard template.
I do not want to recreate parts of the Button standard template by drawing 2D shapes.
How can I reference parts of the Button standard template in my RadioButton template ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `Template` of `Button` to `RadioButton` and you are good to go.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <StackPanel.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
       <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                    Name="border"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
              <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                             Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                             ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding 
                                               ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                             ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding 
                                           ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
                             Name="contentPresenter"
                             Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                             HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding 
                                             Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                             VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding 
                                             Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
                             SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding 
                                                  UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                             Focusable="False" />
           </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
     </Style>
  </StackPanel.Resources>
  <RadioButton Content="First"/>
  <RadioButton Content="Second"/>
  <RadioButton Content="Third"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Create the default style under your StackPanel resources so that it gets applied automatically to all radioButtons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have applied the style you provided but the templated RadioButtons do not look like standard Buttons.

Comment: Yeah ControlTemplate triggers are missing for it. You can look at the complete ControlTemplate from [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tnHmuVcJ). Copy/paste complete template from there and that should work for you.

Comment: I have applied the ControlTemplate you provided but the templated RadioButtons still do not look like standard Buttons. The templated RadioButtons look like flat Buttons. How did you get the ControleTemplate you provided ?

Comment: You can try default templates as provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328(v=vs.110).aspx). Basic idea was you have to override ControlTemplate of radio button and supply it template of Button.